# EditText is null

Tags: android, android-edittext

I can't figure out why my EditText is null.

```
public ChoiceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_view, this, true);

        Log.d("TEST CHOICEVIEW", "1");
        et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.enterChoice);
        if (et == null) Log.d("TEST CHOICEVIEW", "null"); // << this always produces "null" in Logcat
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choiceViewTextView);
        Log.d("TEST CHOICEVIEW", "2");
        choiceString = et.getText().toString();
        Log.d("TEST CHOICEVIEW", "3");
        tv.setText(choiceString);

        Log.d("TEST CHOICEVIEW", "4");

        requestLayout();
    }
```

and the xml file where the EditText is found (is not choice_view...is that an issue?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterChoice"
        android:hint="@string/enterChoiceText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and just for the sake of thoroughness, the choice_view.xml file associated with the ChoiceView class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choiceViewTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

When I run this, Logcat produces the following before crashing:

```
TEST CHOICEVIEW 1
TEST CHOICEVIEW null
TEST CHOICEVIEW 2
AndroidRuntime Shutting down VM
```

Let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks!

Additional info:

- ChoiceView is called from the ChoiceList class from the following code:

  ```
  Context context = ChoiceList.this;
  ChoiceView cv = new ChoiceView(context);
  ```

Comment: Are you sure that `R.layout.choice_view` is the one that contains the EditText?  You didn't label the filename for the layouts.

Comment: is enterChoice in choice_view layout?

Comment: Can we see the code that is instantiating ChoiceView pls?

Comment: If ChoiceView is being inflated, then use the other constructors.

Comment: Where did "TEST CHOICEVIEW 1" come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the component you are trying to reference to be contained in the XML layout you are inflating.

It looks to me like you are trying to reference Views (EditText) from more than 1 XML file. This is not appropriate

This why you are not finding the view you are looking for -  choiceViewTextView
It is in NOT in the choice_view.xml file (which is the one you are inflating).  Changing this call to reference the layout.xml file (you didn't specify the name for this file) will fix  your issue.

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks so much! I added a new inflater for the xml file containing the EditText and it works. I'm teaching myself how to code android apps from scratch, so I guess I'm missing some of the fundamentals like this. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help, the disconnect between XML and Java is confusing at first, but makes a lot of sense in the long run, and is worth the trouble initially.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inflating the view (assuming the code you posted is in `code_view`) without attaching it to a view group? Like so:

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_view, null);
```

Caused me major headaches in the past.

Comment: You mean like instead of writing
`final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_view, null);`
I would just write
`inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_view, null);`
and later just calling `findViewById()` instead of `view.findViewById()`? If that's what you mean, then yes, I tried that. In fact, I only added the view part because previous threads seemed to insist on it.